# Не могу взять значение из input node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Ребята, всем привет, помогите, пожалуйста, есть ejs файл, в котором есть 2 input, нужно ввести туда значение и по нажатию на кнопку "Поиск" создавать запись в базе данных. Как это лучше сделать? Пробую так, ничего не выходит. Использую Node.js + Express + MongoDB

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/PhotoSearchDB';
var assert = require('assert');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('add_img');
});

router.post('/result', function (req, res, next) {
    var item = {
        name: req.body.name,
        author: req.body.author
    };
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        var collection = db.collection("images");
        collection.insertOne(item, function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('Image inserted!');
            db.close();
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

```html
<div class="pg_content_add_img_form">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Название изображения">
            <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Автор">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div class="pg_content_add_img_button_choose_block">
        <button href="#" class="pg_content_add_img_button_choose">Выбрать изображение</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pg_content_add_img_button_send_block">
        <a href="result">
            <button class="pg_content_add_img_button_send">Начать поиск</button>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте <form action='/result' method='post'>
Кнопку сабмита вставьте в пределы формы ну и как сказано уже в ответе, используйте bodyParser() чтобы node.js мог понять, какие данные со страницы вы пытаетесь записать в базу.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего что вы забыли распарсить содержимое **body**. В Express это делает примерно вот так:

```
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Вставьте этот код сразу после создания **router**